# Is there any documentation for the RegKey provider for Web Farm Framework?

Tags: web-farm, web-farm-framework

Is there any documentation out there for the "Application Provisioning" providers in the Web Farm Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I find part of the answer right after I post my question :). I believe the Web Farm Framework uses the MSDeploy providers. The documentation for those is at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569040(WS.10).aspx.